# Perform Delta Function between elements in PyTorch tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I have a 1 dimensional pyTorch tensor (dtype: int32) and was wondering if there was a way to perform a Dirac Delta function on the elements in this tensor, i.e:

```
f = tensor[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
f_after_dirac_delta = tensor[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

EDIT: as @GirishDattatrayHegde mentioned, the term Dirac-Delta was misleading. The correct term should have been a Kronecker-Delta. My apologies.

Comment: Can you explain about Dirac delta function you are considering? As far as I know, Dirac delta function is just an impulse at zero

Comment: Hi @GirishDattatrayHegde, I intend to use it as a comparison function: if both numbers are exactly the same, then return a 1, else, return a 0. I admit the term might have been misleading, and I apologize for that.

EDIT: I just had a look, it is not a Dirac, rather a Kronecker Delta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to compare successive elemeents of your tensor. This should work :

```
import torch
f = torch.tensor([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1])
f_dirac = (f[1:] == f[:-1]).to(torch.long)
```